# IcCube - Formatting problems

Tags: formatting, iccube

I have two problems regarding the formatting of my table:

1. All of my Dimensions are completely uppercase. If I launch the query in the MDX IDE, I get results as expected, but in the reportingtool (/icCube/doc/ic3report) everything is uppercase. Unfortunately I couldn't find any setting to change that yet.
2. I would like to display my number formatted in the german style (, as decimal sign and . as thousands separator). If I put in my query FORMAT_STRING = '0.000,#' of yourse the system doesn't know, what is meant. Is there a way to tell, how I would like to see the numbers?

Thanks for your help

~Ulrich~

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you be more precise about the 'faulty' widgets and what is badly displayed (dimension name, member name, etc). The Web reporting should not change the case of the model definition.
2. The thousand separator used is defined by the locale not by the FORMAT_STRING definition. You should define the locale of the user as German. Note, if no locale has been defined then the icCube server (i.e., Java process) locale is used.

Note: in the FORMAT_STRING definition, the '.' represents the decimal separator and the ',' the thousands separator. I believe your example should be: '0,000.#'. More details can be found [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/cellProperties/FORMAT_STRING.php).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have the problem, that all the dimension names in all widgets have only capital letters. Here is a screenshot with the problem: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4090/wl7wfccx_png.htm

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the fact about the locale. I am aware, how the format_string should look. I only wanted to point out, that I tried to change the order and hoped, that the system would then see, what I want to do... Anyway in the cubes definition I could only find a local setting in the time dimension. I changed that, too, but it didn't do anything. And I found out, that users have locales, but apparently this local is not in charge either. So what locale should be changed to get the changed formatting?

Answer (score 0):

After a restart of the IcCube Server the right locale is now recognized and this part is working.

As for the words all in capitals I found out, that this happens, if no style is chosen in the widgets/filters. Once I chose a style, I had everything written as it should.